# Django - Limit User Queries

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to limit a user so that they can only see the Players that are on their Team. What is the best way to go about doing this?

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = ...
    # Whatever other attributes.

class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...
    # Assign players to a team.
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    # Whatever stats you want to keep on the players
```

Comment: Sounds like you should just filter the players by team in the view. Or do you want to do it on the model level?

Comment: I need some way of assigning various Teams to Users

Comment: Can one user be a member of multiple teams?

Answer (score 1):

```
player.team.player_set.all()
```

if a every user is a player:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOne(User)
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...
    # Assign players to a team.
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    # Whatever stats you want to keep on the players
```

and in your view:

```
request.user.player.team.player_set.all()
```